# How to call bash scripts inside a sh_binary?

Tags: bash, bazel

I have two shell scripts. One (a) prints `"Hello"` and the other one (b) prints `"World"`. I want to have a Bazel target (c) that calls both scripts and gives me `"Hello World"`.

My attempt:

```
mkdir BashScriptDemo
cd BashScriptDemo
touch WORKSPACE.bazel # empty WORKSPACE file
touch BUILD.bazel # empty BUILD file
mkdir my_package
cd my_package
echo '3.5.0' > .bazelversion # use Bazel 3.5.0
echo 'echo -n "Hello"' > a.sh # echo Hello
echo 'echo " World!"' > b.sh # echo World! 
echo './a.sh\n./b.sh' > c.sh # script c that calls a and b 
chmod +x a.sh b.sh c.sh
echo 'sh_binary(name="a",srcs=["a.sh"])' > BUILD.bazel
echo 'sh_binary(name="b",srcs=["b.sh"])' >> BUILD.bazel
echo 'sh_binary(name="c",srcs=["c.sh"],data=[":a", ":b"])' >> BUILD.bazel
buildifier BUILD.bazel # optional in the case you have buildifier installed
bazel run //my_package:c # Bazel is an alias to bazelisk
```

When I try to run the script I get this error:

```
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/2e3943447179c1e4f0f547d49ba1444f/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_package/c: line 1: ./a.sh: No such file or directory
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/2e3943447179c1e4f0f547d49ba1444f/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_package/c: line 2: ./b.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do I need to change the `BUILD.bazel` file (or any other file) to get the desired output?

Comment: maybe use absolute path? or add cd my_package to the script

Comment: The working directory of a script (referred to by `./` in the script) has nothing to do with the location of the script; it's inherited from whatever runs the script. See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for some options on how to find the script's location (and hence other files in the same directory).

Comment: That is a good concise example of how to recreate your setup.  I applaud you for your effort and question.  However, It would be easier to read if it simply showed the various files in context.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the problem is not with the script.  It is a problem with bazel that it can not locate the bash script to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[runfiles.bash](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash) is the preferred way to find paths to [runfiles](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#runfiles) from a shell script. Documentation is in comments at the top of the linked file.

For your example, this should do it:

```sh
# --- begin runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---
# Copy-pasted from the Bazel Bash runfiles library v2.
set -uo pipefail; f=bazel_tools/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash
source "${RUNFILES_DIR:-/dev/null}/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "${RUNFILES_MANIFEST_FILE:-/dev/null}" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
source "$0.runfiles/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.exe.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  { echo>&2 "ERROR: cannot find $f"; exit 1; }; f=; set -e
# --- end runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---

"$(rlocation my_workspace/a)"
"$(rlocation my_workspace/b)"
```

You also need to add the dependency from the shell script by replacing the line in your `BUILD.bazel` with:

```py
sh_binary(
  name = "c",
  srcs = ["c.sh"],
  data = [
    ":a",
    ":b",
  ]),
  deps = ["@bazel_tools//tools/bash/runfiles"],
)
```

And name your workspace by adding this to your `WORKSPACE`:

```py
workspace(name = "my_workspace")
```